# Android. Иногда SoundPool не воспроизводит мелодию

Tags: java, android

Проблема заключается в том, что бывает, при первом за день запуске приложения, SoundPool не воспроизводит мелодию. Activity запускается, а мелодии нет. Хотя при последующих запусках SoundPool работает без проблем и мелодия запускается.

Таким образом я объявляю SoundPool и id мелодии:

```
SoundPool soundPool; //Soundpool
int soundID; //Id мелодии
```

Таким образом я инициализирую SoundPool, загружаю и запускаю мелодию:

```
soundPool=new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM,0); //Инициализируем SoundPool
soundID= soundPool.load(this, R.raw.mysound,1); //Загружаем мелодию
soundPool.play(soundID, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1); //Запускаем мелодию
```

Могу предположить, что SoundPool не успевает загружаться, однако при незамедлительной переустановке приложения и повторной проверке всё работает.

> Если ошибка может быть в самом Activity, то для полноты картины
>   объясню. У меня есть Activity, которое запускается в определённый
>   момент времени при помощи AlarmRecever. Чтобы оно запускалось, когда
>   устройство находится в спящем режиме, то в Activity используется этот код:

```
@Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }
```

Надеюсь изложил проблему понятно. Рассчитываю на вашу помощь.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить слушатель загрузки [`SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setOnLoadCompleteListener(android.media.SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener)) и запускать воспроизведение в нём.